# Bash exec explanation

Tags: bash, exec, io-redirection

What does this line from a bash script do? Specifically the exec redirection.

```
exec > >(tee -i file)
```

Note the spaces between the >

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me which part of that bash statement you didn't fully understand. I assumed you meant the action of the `exec` command, since that's what you put in the title. If you don't understand the "redirect to a process substitution" syntax, please ask another more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It changes the current shell's `stdout` so that it outputs both to the file named `file` and to the previous `stdout` (which was presumably a terminal window).

It does not modify `stderr`, so not all output will be logged.

In general, `exec` with a set of redirections and no executable applies the redirections to the current shell.

Comment: Just being curious: Do I need to write `exec` then, or can I also do just a , i.e., `1> >(tee -i file)`?

Comment: @user1934428: you need the `exec` command.

Comment: What is the second ">" doing? Isn't one ">" enough for a redirection?

Comment: @Silicomancer: the second `>` is part of `>(` which starts a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).